# Problem with getting the right values of the signals in my vhdl code

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I am working on my diploma thesis and I am writing in VHDL. In my code as it is shown below, I have assigned values to the two signals (`counting` and `get_lbp_from_blks`) at the same time. However, in my simulation wave in Modelsim I see that signal `get_lbp_from_blks` gets value `1` two cycles earlier than signal `counting`. Do you have any idea why is this happening? [Waveform from Modelsim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4QA2.jpg)

```
if (making_blocks = '1') then 
    ...doing some stuff...
    making_blocks <= '0';
    get_lbp_from_blks <= '1';
    counting <= '1';
    incr_i <= '1';
end if;
```

PS: Modelsim shows me a message

```
** Warning: Design size of 34160 statements or 279 leaf instances exceeds ModelSim PE 
Student Edition recommended capacity.
 Expect performance to be quite adversely affected.".
```

Is there any possibility that this affects my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The message just means Modelsim will run artificially slow. It won't affect the simulation results. Most likely something else in your code is driving one or both signals; only you can tell what.

Comment: Take a look at the signals in the dataflow view, this shows you where signals change their value.